# Doubling input array when using numpy for fast fourier transforms

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I wrote a function that returns the real component of the fast four transform of a grid.

```
def take_FFT(x):
    # some arbitrary field for a 1D grid
    y = abs(1.0/x)
    # compute FFT (in general multi-dimensional) array of real numbers
    y_k = np.fft.rfftn(y)

    #compute the inverse FFT
    y_invk = np.fft.irfftn(y_k)
    return y,y_k, y_invk # return fourier transform and inv transform

# initialize sample x
x_test = np.arange(-5,5,0.001)

field,FFT_test, inv_test = take_FFT(x_test)
```

How do I make an appropriate new "x array" to plot against the FFT? It is not clear to me how to make an array of length = (n/2)+1, like the one that np.fft.irfftn returns

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow, @Messier!

If I understand your question correctly, you want to [`slice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) a `numpy.array`.

Suppose we have a `numpy.array` `arr` that has length `N`. Then to slice up to length `M` (such that `M<=N`) or up to `(N/2)+1`:

```
sliced_arr = arr[:M]
slice_half = arr[:N//2+1]
```

where in `python` versions `3` or greater, `N//2` does integer division.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get an array of frequencies to be used with [`np.fft.rfft`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html#numpy.fft.rfft) is to make use of the convenient helper function [`np.fft.rfftfreq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfftfreq.html#numpy.fft.rfftfreq):

```
freqs = np.rfftfreq(x_test)
```

The multi-dimentional equivalent for [`np.fft.rfftn`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfftn.html#numpy.fft.rfftn) is slightly more complicated. You will need to get the frequencies along each axes, then use [`np.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html):

```
per_axis_freq = [np.fft.fftfreq(N) for N in x_test.shape[0:-1]]
per_axis_freq.append(np.fft.rfftfreq(x_test.shape[-1]))
freqs = np.meshgrid(*per_axis_freq[::-1])
```